# Recommended modding guide for Baldurs Gate?

Tags: mods, baldurs-gate

I have purchased the GOG editions of Baldurs Gate 1 and 2 and I'm looking for a little help in getting them modded up to a recommended level for a play through suitable for someone who has never played these games before.

I've seen a number of different guides and suggestions scattered around the internet and to be quite honest I find it a little confusing.

I'd appreciate it if someone could compile a brief list of recommended mods or patches I should apply.

Comment: Sorry, Rob.  Arqade doesn't do recommendations very well, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can have a look http://www.moddb.com/games/baldurs-gate-tales-of-the-sword-coast/mods and http://www.moddb.com/games/baldurs-gate-ii/mods

Comment: And gog.com has its own nice entry: http://www.gog.com/news/enhance_the_gameplay_in_your_edition_of_baldurs_gate_from_gogcom and http://www.gog.com/news/mod_spotlight_baldurs_gate_reloaded_nwn2_mod